# How to edit the title of picture?

Tags: subfloats

I write latex with IEEEtrans with TexLive version 2022

I would like to have the following format:

a. There is only (a) and (b) on each respective figure.

b. Title of Figure consists of the general description with respective description for (a) and (b).

[image: expectation]

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[ht]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \centering
        \subfloat[Picture A]{
         \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Picture_A.png}
         \label{fig: first}}
         
        \subfloat[Picture B]{
         \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Picture_B.png}
         \label{fig: second}}
    \caption{Picture 1}
    \label{fig: Picture}
\end{figure}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The result is as follows.

[image: result]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (from Your code):

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
        \centering
        \subfloat[]{
            \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Picture_A.png}
            \label{fig: first}}
        
        \subfloat[]{
            \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Picture_B.png}
            \label{fig: second}}
        \caption{Picture A and Picture B}
        \label{fig: Picture}
    \end{figure}
    
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```